# Applications of Frameworks

Tags: java, frameworks, libraries

I have read enough posts on what a framework is and how it is different from a library..including the Inversion of Control.

Just one question left unanswered
Are Frameworks only for User Interfaces, Where the framework keeps listening to User requests and then call programmer's custom code when needed?
Can someone please provide example of any other type of framework which is not for GUI? Like java or C++ codes always start with Main() and follow the path set by the programmer..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The Spring Framework is one such example.

Also, I think you might have misunderstood inversion of control. In very simple terms, it means that instead of the *programmer* being in control of what happens, it's the *framework*. So while it's true that it starts with a `main`, it doesn't necessarily mean that the user is in control of what happens

The way that the Spring Framework works is actually very simple from the programmer's perspective - you can add features by using the proper annotations e.g. `@Controller`, `@Service`/`@Component`, `@Configuration`, etc. and if you want to modify Spring's behavior, you generally override the beans by declaring a `@Bean` on a method that returns the type of the class you want to override. e.g.:

```
@Bean
public PasswordEncoder passwordEncoder() {
    return new BCryptPasswordEncoder();
}
```

In this example, you wouldn't have to do anything other than that, because the Spring Framework will take care of detecting all `@Bean` annotations and adjust itself accordingly.

That's just a rough explanation on how the Spring Framework works, but it should help you understand a little better.

Comment: Thanks for the reply!! After reading a bit more, got to know how Dependency Injection also achieves IOC where the program runs thru main() and user it still not int control.
have not read Springs, will go through and come back if any doubts!!

Comment: Could you please provide any layman example of NON GUI framework meanwhile!! All I get is Web or Application GUI examples where you have the skeleton..say for menu bar or layout of web page and you just push your content in it like the File/Edit/view menus or about us web page. Thanks!!